# Identifying if a paper is developed from LaTeX

Tags: latex-misc

Is there any way to identify if a paper is developed using LaTeX or not. In other words, what are the characteristics of a paper developed using LaTeX. Since the term paper is too generic, I will reduce it to only research papers say `IEEE` or `elsevier` or `ACM`. But answers to other types of papers are also allowed.

The reason I am asking this question is, while reading an IEEE paper, I found a range written like this `20 % to 60 %`, which is not advisable(to my understanding).

In the paper:

[image]

In LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{20}{\percent} to \SI{60}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Document properties?

Comment: Can you please elaborate @PauloCereda

Comment: If I get one of my papers and `pdfinfo mypaper.pdf`, I get the document metadata, which can include some interesting info, say, `Creator: LaTeX with hyperref package` and `Producer: pdfTeX-1.40.14`. Of course, this is not definitive and might be misleading. Sadly, IMHO there's no way to be 100% sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "which is not advisable"? What would be advisable?

Comment: Since one can edit (and thus clear) the `creator` and `producer` fields via hyperref, it should always be visible via the font properties. In case of XeLaTeX... hm, good question actually. Well I think it'd be noticeable through some odd embedded Type 3 fonts maybe, in case of missing characters/glyphs?

Comment: These properties (Creator, Producer) can be modify with an external program (like `Adobe Acrobat`). If you use `XeLaTeX` it isn't posible view any difference in the fonts because it use the Operative System fonts.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning for this question. Whether advisable or not, I could type `20 % to 60 %` just as easily in MS Word/LibreOffice/WordPerfect/Google Docs/ *etc.* as I could in a LaTeX source document.

Comment: @PaulGessler please see the edit

Comment: @pluton please see the edit

Comment: @PauloCereda please see the edit

Comment: @skpblack please see the edit

Comment: @subhamsoni that was my point. In (La)TeX, it could be done in an advisable way (with `\SI{60}{\percent}` as you have shown or with `60\,\%`), or in an "inadvisable" way (with `60 \%`). Just because the feature is there to do it "the right way" doesn't mean that users will use it.

Comment: Got it @PaulGessler. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When people say you can do anything with TeX but you shouldn't, they really mean it. So what you are trying to identify with is not a smoking gun. And this question cannot be answered in detail since you can practically do anything with TeX;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\SI{20}{\percent} to \SI{60}{\percent}\newline
20 \% to 60 \%
\end{document}
```

What you need to look for is that extra ugly kerning and strange shift in the reference number etc. When it is flat out and consistently ugly it is with 1-ε probability not TeX. But of course some people tune TeX for extreme ugliness. Coincidentally most of those people work in Thesis Template Preparation Offices of Universities and sometimes IEEE.

[image]

Comment: You should clarify that this example works only if run it with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` because the package `fontspec` is not compatible with `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Comment: @skpblack You can't use system fonts any other way but it's not really an answer anyway..

Answer (score 4):

if you want to distinguish (La)TeX output from other programs it is as hard as to distinguish diamond from cubic zirconia: you need experience. font size, form or ligatures are an indicator but not a proof. you really can do everything with (La)TeX.

Where (La)TeX leave a trace is a flow of text:

- are the spaces (made with *glue*) evenly distributed or jumping wild between narrow and wide in neighbour lines?
- is the hyphenation even?
- is there a difference between -

  - minus
  - hyphen
  - en-dash
  - em-dash

kerning is not good indicator since this is ruled by the font and not by TeX.